# How to merge two string arrays with no duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

I was able to get the two arrays to sort and merge but I can not figure out how to remove the duplicates. Can someone please help me with this? Here is my code so far:

```java
public class FinalArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testArray1 = {"coffee", "tea", "water"};
        String[] testArray2 = {"lemonade", "juice", "water"};
        mergeUniqueValues(testArray1, testArray2);
    }

    public static void mergeUniqueValues(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        String[] arr3 = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            arr3[i] = arr1[i];
        }
        for (int i = arr1.length, index = 0; i < arr1.length + arr2.length; i++, index++) {
            arr3[i] = arr2[index];
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr3);

        System.out.println("Your sorted array is: ");
        for (String str : arr3) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Property of Set: It does not allow duplicates.**

You can simply convert the array to `Set` (to avoid duplicates) and then convert it back to an array.

Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] testArray1 = {"coffee", "tea", "water"};
        String[] testArray2 = {"lemonade", "juice", "water"};
        mergeUniqueValues(testArray1, testArray2);
    }

    public static void mergeUniqueValues(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        Set noDuplicateSet = new HashSet();
        noDuplicateSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));
        noDuplicateSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));

        String[] noDuplicateArray = new String[noDuplicateSet.size()];
        noDuplicateSet.toArray(noDuplicateArray);

        Arrays.sort(noDuplicateArray);

        System.out.println("Your sorted array is: ");
        for (String str : noDuplicateArray) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Your sorted array is: 
coffee
juice
lemonade
tea
water
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java Streams and `distinct()`.

```
String[] result =
  Stream.concat( // combine
    Stream.of(array1),
    Stream.of(array1))
  .distinct()    // filter duplicates
  .sorted()      // sort
  .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage from the `java.util.TreeSet` class, which is a collection which implements `java.util.Set`, and made of all unique values ordered by the natural order of the given elements. In your case, `String` does implement `Comparable`, so it can be naturally ordered when the element are inserted in the collection.

Here is the code you can test:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] testArray1 = { "coffee", "tea", "water" };
        String[] testArray2 = { "lemonade", "juice", "water" };
        
        mergeUniqueValues(testArray1, testArray2);
    }

    public static void mergeUniqueValues(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        
        Set<String> mergedList = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(arr1));
        mergedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));
        String[] arr3 = mergedList.toArray(String[]::new);
        
        System.out.println("Your sorted array is: ");
        for (String str : arr3) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
Your sorted array is: 
coffee
juice
lemonade
tea
water
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Java Stream*:

```java
String[] testArray1 = {"coffee", "tea", "water"};
String[] testArray2 = {"lemonade", "juice", "water"};

String[] testArray3 = Stream.of(testArray1, testArray2)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream).distinct().sorted().toArray(String[]::new);

Arrays.stream(testArray3).forEach(System.out::println);
//coffee
//juice
//lemonade
//tea
//water
```